# Resharper settings in TFS

Tags: resharper, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Currently i want to Run my Resharper in TFS/VSTS , but when i try to run the Code Analayis i am getting this error

2017-08-24T03:25:07.2204073Z ##[section]Starting: Automated code quality checks
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z ==============================================================================
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z Task         : Resharper Code Quality Analysis
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z Description  : Runs the Resharper Command-Line Tool and fails the build if code quality issues are found
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z Version      : 1.0.60
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z Author       : Alan Wales
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z Help         : [More Information](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html)
2017-08-24T03:25:07.2215576Z ==============================================================================
2017-08-24T03:25:08.5800144Z Preparing task execution handler.
2017-08-24T03:25:16.2578820Z ##[error]Found value Registry with no corresponding named parameter
2017-08-24T03:25:16.2618817Z ##[section]Finishing: Automated code quality checks

My Setting for the Resharper in the TFS\VSTS setting is

[Settings in TFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dC5s.png)

Can somebody please suggest me if i have to do any other setting in TFS\VSTS or anything else i need to add in the solution .

Comment: You should add the error message as text, not as a picture.

Comment: I have added the error as text now .

Comment: @anonymous Please check if you correctly download the Resharper CLI task, check if the task already located on the agent, eg  D:\LC\Agent\_work\_tasks\ResharperCli_357e581f-2683-4ac4-aff6-2c2445f063c5\1.0.60 . Normally it should execute the powershell script: D:\LC\Agent\_work\_tasks\ResharperCli_357e581f-2683-4ac4-aff6-2c2445f063c5\1.0.60\RunResharperCodeAnalysisTool.ps1. Just try to uninstal the extension then reinstall it, then try it again.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I have done what is suggested still not working for me ,

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by some blank space entered in the "Path to .sln or .csproj file" field of the task. Remove the blank space and then try again.